# Joomla: Fetching k2 item content by ajax won't increase item hits

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, k2

It is great that k2 supports ajax. Although I have been using k2 for years, I just realized it by reading this blog post: http://getk2.org/blog/786-k2-v257-released-introduces-json-jsonp-content-output and started using ajax to improve my k2 powered websites.

But I have had a problem.

On my page there are both item list from categories and a k2 content module showing the lasted item. I have made it so that when one of the items in the category is clicked, the item content in the module gets updated by ajax.
Live page is here, [aoafinc.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=2&Itemid=150&lang=en-us](http://aoafinc.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=2&Itemid=150&lang=en-us) It is under developed and mostly Chinese, but you get the idea.

It seems good but the problem is, the item hits won't increase. ( I had to use some javascript to fake the item hits number displayed under the title for now ) Is there anyway to solve this? I am thinking maybe I need to hardcode some PHP file so that every time the 'url+&format=json' gets displayed, item hits increases.

Someone has pointed out that there is this function

```
function hit($id)
{

    $row = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
    $row->hit($id);
}
```

in com_k2/models/item.php.

But I really know very little about k2 core and don't know what to do with it, so any direction or hints will be greatly appreciated!

And in some way, I think this is a more general issue than just joomla and k2. If you use ajax to fetch content, how do you make it count for the content hits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under com_k2/views/item, there are `view.html.php` and `view.json.php`, in `view.html.php` line 134

```
// Increase hits counter
$model->hit($item->id);
```

while `view.json.php` doesn't have this line. By adding this line to it, problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. Concerning to hits, you have to also take into account caching. Otherwise, it will only increment when cache is disabled.

You can review how K2 component works to count hits in the same way.